# Dealing with application processmessages

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In our software we have issues with asynchronous execution of events. Sometimes one function will "break into" another one with all kinds of weird results.

I'm dealing here with user-input and timers that fire events.

The issue is that rather then executing the code tied to the events one by one, it's done at the first possible moment that Delphi gives a window for it: application.processmessages. This gives problems in that sometimes half of function A gets done, then function B "breaks in", gets done and after that , the last half of function A gets done. This can give "surprising" results.

Are there good ways to deal with this?

Things I tried:

--

- Using a "busy-flag", this has some ups and downs, mostly that everything you do has to know of it.
- Removing all application.processmessages where I can. This has pretty good results. But we're relying on some 3rd party components which I found out also fire application.processmessages.

Next I was thinking of trying building some kind of "command-queue" where I can receive my events and fire them in a fifo way.

Apart from rebuilding everything we have from the ground up, are there other/better ways to tackle these issues?

Comment: Stop calling ProcessMessages

Comment: Eliminate all your `ProcessMessages` and don't call 3rd party components that includes `ProcessMessages` from timer event handlers.

Comment: You can. Just stop calling it.

Comment: "Just stop calling it" will probably introduce other issues. So I would not see that as a solution for everything. Replace that call with a better suited function instead.

Comment: @SebastianZ What function would that be then? Clearly there will be consequences of stripping out the calls to ProcessMessages. Deal with them and the job is done. Pumping the message queue and allowing re-entrancy is a mug's game.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That depends on the context. But usually it has to do with only processing particular messages.

Comment: @SebastianZ Usually people call ProcessMessages because they don't know what they are doing. The right solution is to stop calling it. Yes that might be painful, but the asker is hardly starting from a good place with re-entrant input event handlers.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there good ways to deal with this?

First eliminate all your use of `ProcessMessages`. As you discovered, it screws up timer event handlers when called from there. Used in other places, it is often subject to race conditions and may hide the real problem. **Find out what that problem is and solve it**.

> But we're relying on some 3rd party components which I found out also fire application.processmessages.

Timer Event handlers are supposed to do only short time work. If you are calling `ProcessMessages` via a call to a 3rd party library inside a timer event handler, eliminate that call. There is no other cure, except rewriting the library or calling it in another way.

> Apart from rebuilding everything we have from the ground up, are there other/better ways to tackle these issues?

Normally you can do background work in threads as well, providing the rules of not calling any VCL RTL methods directly are followed. Here it is not possible if the 3rd party component is calling `ProcessMessages`.

---

If you can't alter the 3rd party component, there is possibility to post a message to your form, and put the call in the method that handles this message. With a modern Delphi you could use [DelayedAction](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited) by @MasonWheeler. But I really recommend you to take the "hard" way and fix the 3rd party lib instead.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to eliminate the call to `Application.ProcessMessages`. Most of the time there is other ways to do what `Application.ProcessMessages` is supposed to do. You'll need to take a closer look why you need that call, and then find a better solution. For example, you don't need `Application.ProcessMessages` to update the UI. There is other ways to do that.

If a 3rd party component is calling `Application.ProcessMessages` then contact that vendor that they should replace this call with a better suited function. If this is not an option, you can try using workarounds like using that component in a thread (if possible). Or create an invisible modal window and execute the methods of the component inside the ShowModal function. That will at least avoid user input messages. (The "invisible modal window" is a Form with `BorderStyle=bsNone`, size=1×1 and 100% transparency).

Comment: You are suggesting calling ProcessMessages in a thread. Leaving aside not accessing VCL objects from a thread, you'll suppress pumping of main thread's message queue. IOW,  you are assuming third party has called application.processmessages for nothing. That doesn't seem to be a reasonable assumption.

Comment: ShowModal will not avoid user input messages. The modal loop, in fact, calls processmessage (the same thing processmessages calls), it will retrieve whatever message that is posted.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz these are workarounds that are not meant to be perfect. Whether or not they can be used depends on the circumstances. ShowModal does not avoid user input messages. But a modal window disables the owner windows and will not process user input if there is nothing on it that can receive the input.
It is not always possible to use a thread and it is not always the solution. But I've also seen components that were designed to be used in a thread where it does not affect the main thread if they call ProcessMessages. That vendor was way too big for a complaint.

Comment: You don't have to fiddle with invisible forms if what you want is to disable all forms, call disabletaskwindows instead. ... A component advertised to be used in a thread should not be accessing the VCL Coming from a big vendor, that's quite interesting.

Comment: `DisableTaskWindows` disables all windows. But in my experience it is better to have an active window on top.

Comment: Quite weird to discuss disabletaskwindows as a mechanism to avoid application.processmessages, nevertheless you are wrong, pass the handle of the window that you want to remain active to disabletaskwindows.